# Heap corruption in log4cplus

Tags: c++, allocation, heap-corruption

I'm to the point where I need some extra eyes looking at the problem.  Our application uses log4cplus internally.  Presently, our product is supported on CentOS 6.x.  I'm working on moving our product to CentOS 7.  I get this error `*** Error in '/usr/bin/python': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000071c740 ***`.

Examining the stack trace shows that the issue comes from within the log4cplus code.  Our code calls `log4cplus::initialize()` and then opens an appender as follows:

```
void InitializeAppender(std::string fileName)
{
    // Default appender will be rolling files that roll at 10MB.
    // Immediate flush is set to true for now. This is great for testing, but may not be so good for general use...
    log4cplus::SharedAppenderPtr appender(new log4cplus::RollingFileAppender(fileName, 1024 * 1024 * 10, 2, true, false));

    std::auto_ptr<log4cplus::Layout> pLayout(new log4cplus::PatternLayout("%D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%q} %-5p [%i] [%t] %-x %m%n"));
    appender->setLayout(pLayout);

    log4cplus::Logger root = log4cplus::Logger::getRoot();
    root.removeAllAppenders();
    root.addAppender(appender);
}
```

It is at the very first line in this function where the descent into log4cplus code eventually causes the heap corruption (from what I can tell at least) and the segmentation fault.

The code of log4cplus is too numerous for this post so I shall only post the relevant portions (if you're curious for the full "sha-bang" you can download from sourceforge, I was going to provide a link but sourceforge is offline at the moment, if you do get source, I'm using 1.2.0-rc3).  An excerpt from the stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007f94e977a5c9 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f94e977bcd8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f94e97badb7 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f94e97c219d in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f94e2357bca in _M_dispose (__a=..., this=0x22759e0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:249
#5  ~basic_string (this=0x7fff5bdbbc00, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:539
#6  log4cplus::helpers::LogLog::set_tristate_from_env (result=result@entry=0x2259e90, 
envvar_name=envvar_name@entry=0x7f94e2482c0b "LOG4CPLUS_LOGLOG_DEBUGENABLED") at src/loglog.cxx:155
#7  0x00007f94e2357d2f in log4cplus::helpers::LogLog::get_debug_mode (this=0x2259e88) at src/loglog.cxx:145
```

You'll notice that `log4cplus::helpers::LogLog::get_debug_mode` calls into `log4cplus::helpers::LogLog::set_tristate_from_env`.  At the exit of `set_tristate_from_env`, the destructors for `std::basic_string<>` are called.  Something before hand has corrupted the heap and I'm not sure where.  These two functions are rather innocuous but I'm posting them anyway.

```
// from loglog.cxx in log4cplus sources
// tchar is typedef char tchar in this build (it is not UNICODE)
// at least, I believe that to be the case.  I will test.
// TriState is an enum with 3 values
void
LogLog::set_tristate_from_env (TriState * result, tchar const * envvar_name)
{
    tstring envvar_value;
    // the prototype for get_env_var()
    //  get_env_var(tstring& value, tstring const& name)
    bool exists = internal::get_env_var (envvar_value, envvar_name);
    bool value = false;
    if (exists && internal::parse_bool (value, envvar_value) && value)
        *result = TriTrue;
    else
        *result = TriFalse;
}
```

And the code for get_debug_mode

```
// also from loglog.cxx in log4cplus sources
// LOG4CPLUS_TEXT macro is an indirection for adding the preceding
// 'L' to the string necessary when UNICODE aware.  Otherwise, it's
// simply the string
bool
LogLog::get_debug_mode () const
{
    if (LOG4CPLUS_UNLIKELY (debugEnabled == TriUndef))
        set_tristate_from_env (&debugEnabled,
            LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ("LOG4CPLUS_LOGLOG_DEBUGENABLED"));

    return debugEnabled && ! get_quiet_mode ();
}
```

Just in case it's relevant, here's the code for `get_env_var` called from `set_tristate_from_env`

```
// from env.cxx in log4cplus sources
bool
get_env_var (tstring & value, tstring const & name)
{
#if defined (_WIN32) && defined (UNICODE)
    tchar const * val = _wgetenv (name.c_str ());
    if (val)
        value = val;

    return !! val;

#else
    char const * val
        = std::getenv (LOG4CPLUS_TSTRING_TO_STRING (name).c_str ());
    if (val)
        value = LOG4CPLUS_STRING_TO_TSTRING (val);

    return !! val;

#endif
}
```

Comment: "Error in '/usr/bin/python'" looks very strange. I'm fairly sure that log4cplus is a red herring and that something in your own code has caused the corruption, possibly long before these symptoms occur.

Comment: @molbdnilo I should have mentioned then that this "application" is a C++ library exposed in python through boost.  That's why you see */usr/bin/python*.  I, also, am beginning to think this.  The stuff happening in what I've posted just doesn't seem to be suspect enough.

Comment: Oh. That's quite few places where things can go wrong, but the C++-Python binding is probably the most fragile part. I'm afraid I can't offer anything more than wishing you the best of luck.

Comment: It's possible that the heap is already corrupted before InitializeAppender() is called. You may try valgrind.

Comment: I would also suggest trying it under valgrind. If that fails, maybe try to use [`mcheck()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html) to narrow the memory corruption.

Comment: @HenryHu I have run valgrind already.  This is really my first time using the tool and the output is *too overwhelming* to put into words.  I get numerous statements like this, "Invalid write of size 8 .... Address 0x65e0fd8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 664 alloc'd."  I could write a whole new article to SO on just this.  That not withstanding, the corruption is definitely not in log4cplus.  I've made a test driver program and initialized the logger as we do in our library.  There's no problem.

Comment: I should add that, for comparison, I ran this code through valgrind on CentOS 6 (on which we currently support our product) and the output was stark by comparison to what I have in CentOS 7.  There are no problems.

Comment: @wilx Thank for the suggestion for mcheck().  I've not heard of the functionality before.  I wonder though, how would I employ that since my "application" is actually a class library loaded in python?  The docs made me think that it works only with the "outer-most" program.  Is this true?